# Using Okta OpenId Connect "A client_id must be provided in the request"

Tags: federated-authentication

I am trying to use Sitecore 10.0.1, IdentityServer4, with Okta and OpenID Connect.  When I click logout I get this error:

```
{"errorCode":"invalid_client","errorSummary":"A client_id must be provided in the request.","errorLink":"invalid_client","errorId":"oaevKZNtJFrRjqTZ_wCOsx6lA","errorCauses":[]}
```

Here is the OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut code:

```
                options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut += (Func<RedirectContext, Task>)(context =>
                {
                    context.Request.QueryString.Add("client_id", identityProvider.ClientId); // Did not fix issue
                    context.Options.ClientId = identityProvider.ClientId;  // Did not fix issue
                    context.Options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "https://id.myproject.localhost";
                    _logger.LogInformation("Redirect to identity provider for sign out. ClientId: {0}",
                        context?.Options?.ClientId);

                    context.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("id_token")?.Value;  // This returns null
                    _logger.LogInformation("IdTokenHint: {0}", context.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint);

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                });
```

```
                options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider += (Func<RedirectContext, Task>)(context =>
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Redirect to identity provider. IdToken: {0}.",
                        context.ProtocolMessage.IdToken);

                    var first = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("idp");
                    if (string.Equals(first?.Value, identityProvider.AuthenticationScheme, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                        context.ProtocolMessage.Prompt = "select_account";
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                });
```

I was thinking this might be related to IdTokenHint but I don't seem to have that available.

Comment: Is this for the CM/Business users or the front website?

Comment: Also, it may be helpful if you please share your code around how you are redirecting to the Identity provider. For example, how are you handling the `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` event?

Comment: This is for the CM/Business users

Comment: I added the OnRedirectToIdentityProvider to the post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and resolved it by storing the `IdToken` in a persistent storage so it can be retrieved later during logout. In our case it is in Redis and we used the same approach as my answer [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/26785/2495), but this can obviously be different depending on your solution. I'm assuming you have access to `IdToken` in `SecurityTokenValidated` event?

Answer (score 3):

In the `AddOpenIdConnect` function set `options.SaveTokens = true;` then you can retrieve the token in the `OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut` handler using the `GetTokenAsync` extension method from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` namespace.

```
options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut += (Func<RedirectContext, Task>)(async context =>
{
   context.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = await context.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken);
});
```

Comment: thanks, this works locally but fails in staging. May be due to strict policies in staging for saving tokens?

Answer (score 1):

I have working code I have used with IdentityServer4 that I believe should work with Okta.
The full solution is [available on my repo here](https://github.com/JuliusAngwenyi/SitecoreHostPlugins/blob/master/Avanade.SitecoreIdentityPlugins/AvanadePlugin.IdentityProvider.Ids4Demo/ConfigureSitecore.cs).

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Ids4DemoIdentityProvider identityProvider = this._appSettings.Ids4DemoIdentityProvider;
        if (!identityProvider.Enabled)
            return;
        this._logger.LogDebug("Configure '" + identityProvider.DisplayName + "'. AuthenticationScheme = " + identityProvider.AuthenticationScheme + ", ClientId = " + identityProvider.ClientId, Array.Empty<object>());
        new AuthenticationBuilder(services).AddOpenIdConnect(identityProvider.AuthenticationScheme, identityProvider.DisplayName, (Action<OpenIdConnectOptions>)(options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme    = "idsrv.external";
            options.ClientId        = identityProvider.ClientId;
            options.Authority       = identityProvider.Authority;
            options.MetadataAddress = identityProvider.MetadataAddress;
            options.CallbackPath    = "/signin-idsrv";
            options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider += (Func<RedirectContext, Task>)(context =>
            {
                Claim first = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("idp");
                if (string.Equals(first != null ? first.Value : (string)null, identityProvider.AuthenticationScheme, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    context.ProtocolMessage.Prompt = "select_account";
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
        }));
    }
```

I suggest you try with this and see if this resolves your issue

Comment: We found that the context.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint is not set on logout.  But if we breakpoint / copy that value on login then breakpoint / pasted the value in logout it works.  How can we persist that value for use in logout?

Comment: Did quick search and this might help you: Add id_token in list of claims in SecurityTokenValidated callback and used this in RedirectToIdentityProvider callback". Read more here:  https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2334

Comment: Another one of our developers found this:
context.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = await context.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken);

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to set **SignOutScheme** in **OpenIdConnectOptions** of **AddOpenIdConnect**:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIDConnectAuthenticationScheme, oidcOptions =>
    {
        oidcOptions.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
        oidcOptions.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-callback-oidc";
        oidcOptions.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;  //Code Flow
        oidcOptions.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        oidcOptions.SaveTokens = true;
        oidcOptions.UseTokenLifetime = false;
        oidcOptions.ClaimActions.Add(new AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.Claims.MapAllClaimsAction());
        oidcOptions.SignOutScheme = OpenIDConnectAuthenticationScheme;  //<-- Important

        configuration.Bind($"Authentication:OpenIDConnect", oidcOptions);   //Sets Authority, ClientId and ClientSecret

        if (!(oidcOptions.Scope?.Any() ?? false))
        {
            //Add default scopes
            oidcOptions.Scope.Clear();
            oidcOptions.Scope.Add("openid");
            oidcOptions.Scope.Add("profile");
            oidcOptions.Scope.Add("email");
        }
    });
```