# How to get the Azure AD access token from Sitecore Identity Server after using the Azure AD login and use the token for call to external APIs?

Tags: federated-authentication, identity-server, authentication, azure-ad

I have a Sitecore 9.2 application and a feature project for Web API . In the API controller classes I need to get the access token issued from Azure AD after using the Azure AD login on my Sitecore Identity Server.

I am unable to access the token at present as I don't know how to access it. My current .NET Framework version is 4.7.2 .

Comment: Hey Nidhi and welcome to Sitecore community. To help you resolve your problem, please append your code / configs to your question

Answer (score 1):

You can access `IdToken` in `SecurityTokenValidated` or `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider`  event within your `ConfigureServices` OWIN pipeline.

You may need to persist this `IdToken` in say `Redis` to access it elsewhere in your business logic.

We have examples of how this has been done, such as in [this post](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/26774/storing-custom-data-in-redis/26785#26785) and [this one](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/28586/using-okta-openid-connect-a-client-id-must-be-provided-in-the-request/28587?noredirect=1#comment42000_28587)

Sample `ConfigureServices` snippet, original code on [my repo](https://github.com/JuliusAngwenyi/SitecoreHostPlugins/blob/master/Avanade.SitecoreIdentityPlugins/AvanadePlugin.IdentityProvider.Ids4Demo/ConfigureSitecore.cs). You can see the `context.ProtocolMessage.IdToken` is available for you.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    Ids4DemoIdentityProvider identityProvider = this._appSettings.Ids4DemoIdentityProvider;
    if (!identityProvider.Enabled)
        return;
    this._logger.LogDebug("Configure '" + identityProvider.DisplayName + "'. AuthenticationScheme = " + identityProvider.AuthenticationScheme + ", ClientId = " + identityProvider.ClientId, Array.Empty<object>());
    new AuthenticationBuilder(services).AddOpenIdConnect(identityProvider.AuthenticationScheme, identityProvider.DisplayName, (Action<OpenIdConnectOptions>)(options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme    = "idsrv.external";
        options.ClientId        = identityProvider.ClientId;
        options.Authority       = identityProvider.Authority;
        options.MetadataAddress = identityProvider.MetadataAddress;
        options.CallbackPath    = "/signin-idsrv";
        options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider += (Func<RedirectContext, Task>)(context =>
        {
            Claim first = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("idp");
            if (string.Equals(first != null ? first.Value : (string)null, identityProvider.AuthenticationScheme, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                context.ProtocolMessage.Prompt = "select_account";
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
    }));
}
```